# How can I get guard-rspec to print the failed tests?

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard, rspec3

I'm just starting out with rspec and guard. It seems that there's a formatting problem any time a test fails. I get the following error message:

```
15:57:39 - ERROR - Failed: "bundle exec rspec -f progress -r /home/gabriel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.6.2/lib/guard/rspec_formatter.rb -f Guard::RSpecFormatter --failure-exit-code 2  spec/investopedia_accessor_spec.rb" (exit code: 1)
```

There's an uninitialized constant error in my rspec code, but shouldn't it still display some formatted tests?

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: does this work when not using guard?

Comment: No, it doesn't, is this normal output when there's an error in RSpec?

Comment: You can run guard in debug mode with `-d` to get a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: @user2130130 if there is an error with RSpec, as in how the gem was bundled (nothing with your tests), then yes errors like this happen. However, if the error was with your tests (meaning a line failed to pass), then output would be "Failures:", what was expected vs what actually happened, and a small backtrace.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm new at this